# pandas `all` operation : all(df) != df.all()

Tags: python, pandas

I was wanting to compare two dfs and ran into this :

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{'a':1,'b':2},{'a':3,'b':4}])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([{'a':0,'b':2},{'a':3,'b':4}])
```

The element-by-element comparison works as I would have thought:

```
df == df2 
Out[52]:
       a     b
0  False  True
1   True  True
```

But `all(df)` is puzzling me :

```
all(df==df2)
Out[53]: True
```

while

```
(df==df2).all()
Out[54]:
a    False
b     True
dtype: bool
```

Comment: When you use `all(df)`, you're using the built-in `all()` method which takes an iterable and make sure every item is `True`. On the other hand, when you use `(df==df2).all()`, you are using the `pandas.DataFrame.all()` method which checks each axis. The default axis is `0`. That's why you got a `Pandas.Series`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you apply python's `all` function to df (which is an iterable) it returns True if all column names(keys in case of dict) are True(!= 0).
The column name in both your datasets are string (!= 0) which are always translated as True so comparison between them are True. But if you change your dataframe definition as follow :

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{0:1,'b':2},{0:3,'b':4}])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([{0:1,'b':2},{0:3,'b':4}])

df1 = df==df2
print(all(df1))
```

however all values are equal but it throws `False`. Also for dict the following is `False` :

```
mydict = {0 : "Apple", 1 : "Orange"}
print(all(mydict))
```

But if we modify the dict :

```
mydict = {2 : "Apple", 1 : "Orange"}
print(all(mydict))
```

the result becomes `True`